# How can I set a project as trusted when using the gradle :runIde task during IntelliJ Plugin Development

Tags: gradle, intellij-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

the documentation shows that I can configure this via the gui here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-security.html

Each time I have gradle perform `:runIde` it launches a new IDE instance and I have to reconfirm the trusted project directory.

Is there a gradle flag or setting somewhere in the plugin project to set this once for all?

I am using a `kotlin build.gradle.kts` file

*I have configured the trusted root in my 'Parent' IntelliJ IDEA that launches the task, but it seems, is *sometimes* not carried over. Alternatively I would like this to be available when operating from the CLI aswell.

*I am using the `:clean` command alongside the :runIde command, would this affect the settings being erased?